# How to generate/create a same row from the same table with one column condition changed

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

My data looks like this

| date | category | subcategory | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20230510 | A | LMN | 10 |
| 20230510 | A | PQR | 20 |
| 20230511 | A | LMN | 50 |
| 20230511 | A | PQR | 10 |

In my table I am getting subcategory LMN and PQR along with price, I need to introduce row ALL with the addition of the price for LMN and PQR subcategory using optimized query

My expected output is like this

| date | category | subcategory | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20230510 | A | LMN | 10 |
| 20230510 | A | PQR | 20 |
| 20230510 | A | ALL | 30 |
| 20230511 | A | LMN | 50 |
| 20230511 | A | PQR | 10 |
| 20230511 | A | ALL | 60 |

I tried using UNION ALL to generate a row to ALL and the addition of the price at category level and displaying but is there anyway that I can do this same thing without using UNION ALL or SELF JOIN so reduce table scans

Query I tried -

```
select date,
category,
'ALL' as subcategory
sum(price)
from table
group by date,category
UNION ALL
select date,
category,
subcategory,
price
from table;
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and share the expected output ? and also share the query  that you have tried

Comment: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-rollup/

Answer (score 0):

Use the conditional aggregation to get total price of `LMN` and `PQR` only :

```
select *
from mytable
WHERE subcategory in ('LMN','PQR')
UNION ALL
select date, category, 'ALL' as subcategory, sum(case when subcategory in ('LMN','PQR') then price else 0 end)
from mytable
group by date, category
order by date
```

If not interested by filtering your data by subcategory, then :

```
select *
from mytable
UNION ALL
select date, category, 'ALL' as subcategory, sum(price)
from mytable
group by date, category
order by date
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/171G0dXJ)

Answer (score 0):

You could use rollup:

```
with mytable as (select * from (values
                      ('20230510', 'A', 'LMN', 10),
                      ('20230510', 'A', 'PQR', 20),
                      ('20230511', 'A', 'LMN', 50),
                      ('20230511', 'A', 'PQR', 10)) x(date, category,   subcategory,    price))

select date, category, subcategory, sum(price) as price
from mytable
group by  rollup (date, category, subcategory)
order by date,category, subcategory;
```